# What font format should I use for my site

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use a font for my website, I got the overall research and found variety of formats for fonts, Now i want to know that what is the standard format?
Or What are the standard formats?

```
.TTF (True Type Font)
.EOT (Embedded OpenType)
.OTF (open type font)
.SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
.WOFF (Web Open Font Format)
```

So far, I've used all of these formats, something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font';
    src: url('Font.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('Font.eot?#') format('eot'), /* IE6–8 */
         url('Font.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
         url('Font.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
         url('Font.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('Font.svg') format('svg');
}
```

But in this case, the site is too heavy *(size of all formats is almost 1MB)* , So what should i do to be more optimized ?

Comment: you can use .ttf for all other browsers and .eot for internet explore

Comment: Web programming is not about considering and implementing every alternative that can be found. Concentrate on your goal: to support the relevant browsers. Stuff like IE6-9 certainly can be ignored. Use _one_ format, woff or ttf and that's it. Browsers that cannot comply with those are not worth supporting.

Comment: @priya786 do you say just .ttf and .eot ?

Comment: yes i just only prefer you to use only these two format

Comment: @arkascha I love this sentence: _'Browsers that cannot comply with those are not worth supporting.'_

Comment: @arkascha I have a new question, When i attach all font format in my css file, what happen?! I mean: If a user open my website with mobile, then only .svg will be load or all ? also when user use chrome, all attached files will be load on his device or the browser will look for the suitable font a loads it ? tnx

Comment: Not sure about theory actually. Just gave it a short test which showed that chromium requests three font files in parallel.

Comment: @arkascha really i don't know how should i test it ! I want to know if each browser has its own font loading, then I use all formats in my css file.

Comment: They try to find a suitable version and use that. As said before: concentrate on a generally used one and that is enough. Let me as you this way around: what are you afraid of when doing that? Why does it seem to be that important to you to include more versions of the same font? So support e.g. IE-6? _WHY?_

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit obsessed and seeking perfection!! that's make me sad  :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Understanding Font File Types**

- WOFF / WOFF2

WOFF fonts often load faster than other formats because they use a compressed version of the structure used by OpenType (OTF) and TrueType (TTF) fonts.

- SVG / SVGZ

ideal for mobile use

- EOT

supported only by IE

- OTF / TTF

The WOFF format was initially created as a reaction to OTF and TTF, in part, because these formats could easily (and illegally) be copied

- ON THE OTHER SIDE:

Google Fonts offers this as a way to use their fonts.

- SOME PERFORMANCE TIPS

Watch the file size

Fonts can be surprisingly heavy, so lean towards options that offer lighter versions. For example, favor a font set that is 50KB versus one that weighs 400KB.
Limit the character set, if possible

Do you really need the bold and black weights for one font? Limiting your font sets to load only what is used is a good idea and there are some good tips on that here.
Consider system fonts for small screens

Many devices are stuck on crappy connections. One trick might be to target larger screens when loading the custom font using @media.

In this example, screens smaller than 1000px will be served a system font instead and screens that wide and above will be served the custom font.

- CONCLUSION:
  Use OTF/TTF(all browsers) & EOT(I.E) for Desktop screens and use system fonts for small screens as they render faster.
  And do consider google fonts. Best choice so far.

Comment: helpful buddy, please edit your answer and tell my what is your offer in conclusion ?  tnx pal

Comment: then that is right ?! `ttf` and `eot` and `svg` (for mobile)

Comment: you got it right my friend. Infact svg format is the only one allowed by version 4.1 and below of Safari for iOS. SVG fonts are not currently supported by Firefox, IE or IE Mobile. Firefox has postponed implementation indefinitely to focus on WOFF.

Comment: tnx buddy, just a new question, when i attach all format in my web, what happen ?! I mean: if a user open my website with mobile, then only .svg will be load or all ?

Comment: also when user open my website with chrome, then all format will be upload on his system ?

Comment: No. browser in mobile looks for its compatible font type then it gets load on user device.

Comment: I am ashamed to ask again, I want to know, If i use both `.ttf` and `.otf`, This is good ?! Or bad ? Or it does not matter anymore? Or there is no need to ?

Comment: you dont need to. Well It doesn't make sense, Use either of both. Otf is newer than ttf. the benefit of usign otf over ttf is that it is light weight.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested chrome (43) and firefox (37) and ie (10) - in all cases only one font format (respectively: woff, woff and eot) of the five was downloaded. Based on that small sampling, it seems* that including the various file types in your @font-face declaration doesn't have a negative impact on the user. 
*If you happen to know how other browsers behave, let us know.

Comment: +1 for your testing. but a good web developer don't check ONLY the best browser, you should also test some browser like ie 7