# CSS - 'Open Sans' font

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

I have a problem in IE and Edge browsers with using 'Open Sans' font, defined in local .css file.

open-sans.html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'-->
        <link href='open-sans.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 13px;
            }
            .light { 
                font-weight: 300;
            }
            .regular { 
                font-weight: 400;
            }
            .semibold { 
                font-weight: 600;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p class="light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p class="regular">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p class="semibold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

In Chrome or FF i see right fonts (localy i don't have 'Open Sans' installed; OS - Windows 10)... in IE/Edge - the fonts are not working. But if i remove my link to open-sans.css and will use link to fonts.googleapis.com - everything is fine in IE/Edge. What's the reason? (my open-sans.css is a complete copy of "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300")

If you ask why i want to use local open-sans.css? I want to use different font-family defined for 'Open Sans', because right now if user have installed 'Open Sans' font in Win OS - the Chrome browser display them wrong (IE/Edge/FF are fine)

open-sans.css that i'm using:

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTa-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}

/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTZX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTRWV49_lSm1NYrwo-zkhivY.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

/* greek */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTaaRobkAwv3vxw3jMhVENGA.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTf8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF1, U+20AB;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTT0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTegdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mxJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}

/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/RjgO7rYTmqiVp7vzi-Q5URJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/LWCjsQkB6EMdfHrEVqA1KRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

/* greek */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/xozscpT2726on7jbcb_pAhJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/59ZRklaO5bWGqF5A9baEERJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF1, U+20AB;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSq-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}

/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSpX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}

/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShWV49_lSm1NYrwo-zkhivY.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}

/* greek */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSqaRobkAwv3vxw3jMhVENGA.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}

/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSv8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF1, U+20AB;
}

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSj0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

Font in Chrome (if i'm using my local open-sans.css):

[image: Open Sans in Chrome]

Font in IE (if i'm using my local open-sans.css):

[image: Open Sans in IE]

**SOLVED:**

with next css, all is working:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: You'll have to define "wrong" since it seems all the browsers are doing something "wrong" and you're not saying exactly what.

Comment: Can you supply your @font-face code?  Different browsers use different font formats.  There is some good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572159/what-font-format-should-i-use-for-my-site.  Also, you might consider renaming your version of "Open Sans" to avoid conflicts.  Like "Open Sans Custom"

Comment: Thank you Jason, you comment helped (will update my post with new .css, that is working)

Comment: Two things on your solution: first, it's not guaranteed that Google will always keep the same name for the fonts; this is an 'internal' hash which very likely will depend on the version that Google is currently delivering. Your solution is not future-proof. Second, you _can_ put _both_ the `url` for `woff` _and_ `woff2` on the same `src:` — the browser will pick whatever is 'best' (`woff2` is smaller, faster, better — but, as said, IE doesn't work with that format).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your issue is due to `woff2` font format not being supported by IE.

**google font own css will give different font formats to different browser**.

if you open `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300` with chrome you will see `woff2` font format being linked by the served css.
if you open `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300` with IE/Edge you will see `woff2` font format being linked by the served css.

**how to solve**

you either add the woff format to your own open-sans.css or let google do it for you linking the google css

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 13):

in your **css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

.opensans {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the link out of a comment so it can actually grab the font from google.com..

Change this ->

```
<!--link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'-->
```

To this -->

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This will grab the weights you defined..